# How to change the security type from SSL to TLS in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to setup the smtp email notification. I could see that the gmail part works fine. I want to configure it for my office 365.

Smtp server = smtp.office365.com

We don't have SSL configured. Instead we use TLS. How can I set the TLS in the Jenkins?
There is only a check button which suggests to use SSL or not. If I disable it what is it going to use?

I get the following errors -

```
Failed to send out e-mail

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:542)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:374)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1190)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1217)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1201)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: Did you get a solution? I tried everything on this question and related links without any success.

Answer (score 30):

For Jenkins on Windows, open jenkins.xml and modify the arguments node

```
-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080
```

Answer (score 15):

Office 365 indeed requires authenticated SMTP with TLS. The SSL option in the Jenkins configuration does not help, leave it unchecked. Instead add the following system property to the Jenkins VM:

```
-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

For the standalone Jenkins put it in jenkins.xml from the installation folder and for Tomcat update the startup script or use tray icon on Windows.

Then restart jenkins and you're good to go.

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks!  For linux users, add the setting above to the JAVA_ARGS var in your /etc/default/jenkins file.

Answer (score 10):

I run Jenkins under Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I had to adapt the previous answer which addresses CentOS distribution.

First of all, under most Linux distribution, the configuration file for Jenkins is located at `/etc/default/jenkins` ([see this link](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins)). I use Jenkins 2.7 and I append `-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true` to the existant setting variable `JAVA_ARGS`. Finally, I ended with this:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me running Jenkins on CentOS. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and add the option `-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true` to `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`,

If there's some other variable already, append `-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true` to it, so it should be similar to the below:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
```

restart Jenkins with `service jenkins restart` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, I got it fixed. First of all, the JAVA supports by default only SSL. So, Jenkins Java options need to be set to enable TLS. Afterwards, start the Jenkins service. The problem of this permission issue occurs when you don't give the System Admin e-mail address under the Jenkins location column. This doesn't happen for gmail smtp. I guess office 365 has a high security. So, it allows only the registered user to send the emails.

Comment: Can you provide some details on where/how you enabled TLS? And any other tweaks to get it working. I am having the same issue with smtp.office365.com. Thanks!

Comment: Please follow this http://www.tune2wizard.com/linux-jenkins/ . This is tested on Fedora core -16, 19. If you like my answer, please appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding "-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true" to java options didn't work out of the box - Jenkins was trying to connect to the SMTP, but in the the logs at /var/log/maillog (CentOS 7.2) I've seen that the connection is established and then after some time (presumably after time out) postfix has reported "lost connection after CONNECT from {host_name}". I have also connection through TLS. After some research I've decided to try different port - **587** - instead of default 465 and voila! - finally the test email was sent.

Comment: WIth port 587, I am getting below error while testing email in jenkins: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [PN1PR01CA0088.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]        But with port 25, I am getting connection time out...... SMTP server=smtp.office365.com,,,why so?

Answer (score -6):

SSL and TLS are, effectively, the same.

Comment: I have added the logs, kindly suggest what need to be done here.

Comment: As the error message hints, this is a plaintext port, not a TLS port. I tried connecting to it, and it sent me this, in plaintext: "*220 BY2PR03CA036.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 25 Nov 2013 09:47:06 +0000*". (It supports upgrading the connection to TLS, but that's not what the checkbox is for.)

Comment: When I checked  by email settings, it says I have TLS support not SSL. I am just copying all the settings here. But, I can't choose TLS in Jenkins that is the only problem?

Comment: See [this link](http://heylinux.com/en/?p=161). You have to enable TLS upgrade (also known as "STARTTLS") support.