# Unable to send email using Jenkins and SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I am running Jenkins version 1.554.1 on Amazon EC2 Instance
I am using [mailer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer) and currently trying to configure sending emails on failed job builds.
Hitting "test configuration" button gives me `"javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 501 Input line length is too long!"` error.
Screenshot of settings is attached. I also tried to check "Use SSL" checkbox, but result was equal.
What do I miss?
[image: "Test configuration" button hit result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to use my AWS credentials (AWS access key ID and secret access key). This document describes how to create SES credentials: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console

So, solution was to open [SES SMTP Settings](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#smtp-settings:), create new credentials and use them.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I have done the same thing configuring SES with applications.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES requires Transport Layer Security (TLS) connection. This is different than an SSL connection.

I would check the instance OS documentation on setting up TLS.

Here's an SO post about [Jenkins and TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188456/how-to-change-the-security-type-from-ssl-to-tls-in-jenkins)

Comment: Thanks for advice! I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help me. Now Jenkins is running with those parameters, but I got same error: `/usr/bin/java -Xmx384m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/home/ubuntu/jenkins/war --httpPort=80 --ajp13Port=-1 --preferredClassLoader=java.net.URLClassLoader -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 ( I am using image ami-656be372 ubuntu/images/ebs-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20160721 )